# Why is it so difficult to change login screen background?

Tags: login, screen

Why is it so difficult to change the login screen background ?

I've tried everything, dconf-editor, Ubuntu Tweak, and every posted remedy with no luck.

Comment: I'd say this question is off-topic. Can some of the mods close it ?

Comment: You aren't going to see a lot of help from Ubuntu fans while insulting the product we happen to like.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently on Ubuntu 14.10 and if I go to system settings and select appearance, on the right there is a list of wallpapers. Any wallpaper I select also becomes my login screen. If you click the + at the bottom you can add your own and that will become your wallpaper and login screen.

Or are you saying you want your desktop wallpaper to be different than your login screen image?

Comment: I want different for both desktop and login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I am on the same version and I was just able to complete this task by doing the following steps.

Before you get into the main steps you need to move the desired background image to /usr/share/backgrounds. Once the image has been moved you then need to change the ownership of the file.

```
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm filename.jpg
```

Now we can move on to getting it to load and be different than your background.

1. Install dconf-editor

   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
2. Run command to get the root user privilege:

   sudo -i
3. Allow user lightdm to create a connection to the X server:

   xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
4. Switch to user lightdm terminal window.

   su lightdm -s /bin/bash
5. Now you can start the dconf-editor via this user by running:

   dconf-editor

When dconf-editor opens, go to com, then canonical and then click on unity-greeter. The first section is background. Keep the path the same /usr/share/backgrounds, just change the filename to the one you want. Press enter to accept the changes, close and restart. Your done.

Edit: Don't thank me yet I guess. For some reason when you first turn the computer on the login screen shows the desired picture, but as soon as you log in the setting will revert back to whatever the desktop is. When you restart the picture you set comes back. You can see what I am talking about if you lock the desktop right after you log in. From then on out your custom picture is gone till restart.